# Memory leak inside CorDapp flow tests

Tags: kotlin, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory, corda

Inside of my CorDapp, I wrote a custom generateSpend function (attached in a snippet). It uses `tokenSelection.attemptSpend` in conjunction with `generateExit` and `addTokensToRedeem` to spend tokens from various issuers to pay down a single amount.

Example: [Cost is 3 Wood], paid with [2 Wood held by Nick issued by Austin], [1 Wood held by Nick Issued by Nick]

***Is there anything glaringly wrong with my implementation? It’s causing a very strange memory leak error:*** `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

**The tests pass when run in isolation but fail when run all at once**. Note there are one million other things that could be wrong here - I’m using Corda 4.4 latest.

Things I have tried:

- Adjusting the gradle.properties params to add the following JVM Args (No Impact)

  - Xmx2g
  - XX:MaxPermSize=512m
  - XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
  - XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heapdump -XX:+UseG1GC

Code and Error:

```html
/**
 * When a player spends resources in-game, those resources are consumed as inputs to a transaction. The generateInGameSpend
 * method leverages the token-SDK to facilitate the building of transaction proposing the consumption of tokens when they are
 * spent (burned) and not transferred to a counter-party.
 *
 * This method uses the generateExit functionality from the tokenSelection and mutates an input transaction builder in place.
 */
@Suspendable
fun generateInGameSpend(
        serviceHub: ServiceHub,
        tb: TransactionBuilder,
        costs: Map<TokenType, Long>,
        holder: Party,
        changeOwner: Party,
        additionalQueryCriteria: QueryCriteria? = null,
        messageToLog: String = "",
        logger: Logger? = null
): TransactionBuilder {
    // Create a tokenSelector
    val tokenSelection = TokenSelection(serviceHub)
    // Generate exits for tokens of the appropriate type
    costs.filter { it.value > 0 }.forEach { (type, amount) ->
        val baseCriteria = heldTokenAmountCriteria(type, holder)
        val queryCriteria = additionalQueryCriteria?.let { baseCriteria.and(it) } ?: baseCriteria
        // Get a list of tokens satisfying the costs
        val tokensToSpend = tokenSelection
                .attemptSpend(amount of type, tb.lockId, queryCriteria)
        // Run checks on the tokens to ensure the proposed transaction is valid
        val notaryToCheck = tokensToSpend.first().state.notary
        check(tokensToSpend.all { it.state.notary == notaryToCheck }) { "You are trying to spend assets with different notaries." }
        check(tokensToSpend.isNotEmpty()) { "Received empty list of states to spend." }
        // Begin to spend tokens to satisfy costs
        var spentAmount = Amount(0, type)
        tokensToSpend
                .groupBy { it.state.data.issuer }
                .forEach {
                    val amountOfTokens = it.value.sumTokenStateAndRefs().withoutIssuer()
                    spentAmount = spentAmount.plus(amountOfTokens)
                    val (exitStates, change) = tokenSelection.generateExit(
                    it.value,
                    if (spentAmount.quantity > costs[type]!!) Amount(amount, type) else amountOfTokens,
                    changeOwner)
                    addTokensToRedeem(tb, exitStates, change)
                }
    }
    // Return the mutated transaction builder
    return tb
}
?[m io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException: Uncaught exception during scan
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException.newClassGraphException(ClassGraphException.java:89) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1183) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1201) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1214) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at net.corda.core.internal.ClassGraphUtilsKt.pooledScan(ClassGraphUtils.kt:18) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.ClassLoadingUtilsKt.createInstancesOfClassesImplementing(ClassLoadingUtils.kt:22) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$serializationContext$1.apply(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:325) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$serializationContext$1.apply(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:297) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Collections.java:2672) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:322) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$default(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:318) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.internalPrepareVerify$core(LedgerTransaction.kt:217) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:207) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:559) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.flows.SetupGameBoardFlow.call(SetupGameBoardFlow.kt:131) ~[workflows-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.flows.SetupGameBoardFlow.call(SetupGameBoardFlow.kt:33) ~[workflows-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:270) ~[corda-node-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
?[37m[INFO] 16:44:20,066 [Mock network] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Flow error allowed to propagate {actor_id=Only For Testing, actor_owning_identity=O=Mock Company 1, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=TEST, fiber-id=10000775, flow-id=e2b0e443-f602-46ff-ad4d-93f666cca877, invocation_id=602cdfcf-3c0b-4537-a8a8-c8101c1dfe22, invocation_timestamp=2019-11-13T21:43:08.318Z, origin=Only For Testing, session_id=602cdfcf-3c0b-4537-a8a8-c8101c1dfe22, session_timestamp=2019-11-13T21:43:08.318Z, thread-id=7658}
?[m io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException: Uncaught exception during scan
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException.newClassGraphException(ClassGraphException.java:89) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1183) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1201) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1214) ~[classgraph-4.8.41.jar:4.8.41]
    at net.corda.core.internal.ClassGraphUtilsKt.pooledScan(ClassGraphUtils.kt:18) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.ClassLoadingUtilsKt.createInstancesOfClassesImplementing(ClassLoadingUtils.kt:22) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$serializationContext$1.apply(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:325) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$serializationContext$1.apply(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:297) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Collections.java:2672) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:322) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$default(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:318) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.internalPrepareVerify$core(LedgerTransaction.kt:217) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:207) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:559) ~[corda-core-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.flows.SetupGameBoardFlow.call(SetupGameBoardFlow.kt:131) ~[workflows-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.flows.SetupGameBoardFlow.call(SetupGameBoardFlow.kt:33) ~[workflows-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:270) ~[corda-node-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Test Suite 1:

```html
class RobberFlowTests {
private val network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(
        notarySpecs = listOf(MockNetworkNotarySpec(CordaX500Name("Notary", "London", "GB"))),
        networkParameters = testNetworkParameters(minimumPlatformVersion = 4),
        cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.flows"),
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.oracleClientFlows"),
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.contractsAndStates"),
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows"),
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts"),
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.money")
        )
)
)
private val a = network.createNode(MockNodeParameters())
private val b = network.createNode(MockNodeParameters())
private val c = network.createNode(MockNodeParameters())
private val d = network.createNode(MockNodeParameters())
private val oracleName = CordaX500Name("Oracle", "New York", "US")
private val oracle = network.createNode(
        MockNodeParameters(legalName = oracleName).withAdditionalCordapps(
                listOf(
                        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.oracleService")
                )
        )
)

@Before
fun setup() {
    network.runNetwork()
}

@After
fun tearDown() = network.stopNodes()

@Test
fun player1IsUnableToMoveTheRobberWhenA7IsNotRolled() {

    // Get an identity for each of the players of the game.
    val p1 = a.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p2 = b.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p3 = c.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p4 = d.info.chooseIdentity()

    // Issue a game state onto the ledger
    val gameStateIssueFlow = (SetupGameBoardFlow(p1, p2, p3, p4))
    val futureWithGameState = a.startFlow(gameStateIssueFlow)
    network.runNetwork()

    val stxGameState = futureWithGameState.getOrThrow()

    // Get a reference to the issued game state
    val gameState = stxGameState.coreTransaction.outputsOfType<GameBoardState>().single()

    val arrayOfAllTransactions = arrayListOf<SignedTransaction>()
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodes = arrayListOf(a, b, c, d)
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder = gameState.players.map { player -> arrayOfAllPlayerNodes.filter { it.info.chooseIdentity() == player }.first() }

    setupGameBoardForTesting(gameState, network, arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder, arrayOfAllTransactions)
    val gameBoardState = arrayOfAllTransactions.last().coreTransaction.outRefsOfType<GameBoardState>().first().state.data

    val deterministicDiceRoll = getDiceRollWithSpecifiedRollValue(3, 2, gameBoardState, oracle)
    val rollDiceFlow = RollDiceFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, deterministicDiceRoll)
    val futureWithDiceRoll = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(rollDiceFlow)
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithDiceRoll.getOrThrow()

    val futureWithMovedRobber = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(MoveRobberFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, 5))
    network.runNetwork()

    assertFailsWith<TransactionVerificationException.ContractRejection>("The associated dice roll must have a value of 7.") { futureWithMovedRobber.getOrThrow() }
}

@Test
fun player1IsAbleToMoveTheRobberWhenA7IsRolled() {

    // Get an identity for each of the players of the game.
    val p1 = a.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p2 = b.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p3 = c.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p4 = d.info.chooseIdentity()

    // Issue a game state onto the ledger
    val gameStateIssueFlow = (SetupGameBoardFlow(p1, p2, p3, p4))
    val futureWithGameState = a.startFlow(gameStateIssueFlow)
    network.runNetwork()

    val stxGameState = futureWithGameState.getOrThrow()

    // Get a reference to the issued game state
    val gameState = stxGameState.coreTransaction.outputsOfType<GameBoardState>().single()

    val arrayOfAllTransactions = arrayListOf<SignedTransaction>()
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodes = arrayListOf(a, b, c, d)
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder = gameState.players.map { player -> arrayOfAllPlayerNodes.filter { it.info.chooseIdentity() == player }.first() }

    setupGameBoardForTesting(gameState, network, arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder, arrayOfAllTransactions)

    val gameBoardState = arrayOfAllTransactions.last().coreTransaction.outRefsOfType<GameBoardState>().first().state.data

    val deterministicDiceRoll = getDiceRollWithSpecifiedRollValue(3, 4, gameBoardState, oracle)
    val rollDiceFlow = RollDiceFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, deterministicDiceRoll)
    val futureWithDiceRoll = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(rollDiceFlow)
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithDiceRoll.getOrThrow()

    val futureWithClaimedResources = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(MoveRobberFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, 5))
    network.runNetwork()
    val futureWithMovedRobber = futureWithClaimedResources.getOrThrow()

    requireThat {
        val outputRobber = futureWithMovedRobber.coreTransaction.outputsOfType<RobberState>().first()
        "Assert that the robber has been moved to the appropriate position" using (outputRobber.hexTileIndex == HexTileIndex(5))
    }
}

@Test
fun player1IsAbleToApplyTheRobberAfterMovingIt() {

    // Get an identity for each of the players of the game.
    val p1 = a.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p2 = b.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p3 = c.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p4 = d.info.chooseIdentity()

    // Issue a game state onto the ledger
    val gameStateIssueFlow = (SetupGameBoardFlow(p1, p2, p3, p4))
    val futureWithGameState = a.startFlow(gameStateIssueFlow)
    network.runNetwork()

    val stxGameState = futureWithGameState.getOrThrow()

    // Get a reference to the issued game state
    val gameState = stxGameState.coreTransaction.outputsOfType<GameBoardState>().single()

    val arrayOfAllTransactions = arrayListOf<SignedTransaction>()
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodes = arrayListOf(a, b, c, d)
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder = gameState.players.map { player -> arrayOfAllPlayerNodes.filter { it.info.chooseIdentity() == player }.first() }

    setupGameBoardForTesting(gameState, network, arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder, arrayOfAllTransactions)

    val gameBoardState = arrayOfAllTransactions.last().coreTransaction.outRefsOfType<GameBoardState>().first().state.data

    val deterministicDiceRoll = getDiceRollWithSpecifiedRollValue(3, 4, gameBoardState, oracle)
    val rollDiceFlow = RollDiceFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, deterministicDiceRoll)
    val futureWithDiceRoll = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(rollDiceFlow)
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithDiceRoll.getOrThrow()

    val futureWithMovedRobber = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(MoveRobberFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, 5))
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithMovedRobber.getOrThrow()

    val futureWithRobberApplied = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(ApplyRobberFlow(gameBoardState.linearId))
    network.runNetwork()
    val txWithAppliedRobber = futureWithRobberApplied.getOrThrow().coreTransaction

    val inputRobber = txWithAppliedRobber.outputsOfType<RobberState>().single()
    val outputRobber = txWithAppliedRobber.outputsOfType<RobberState>().single()

    requireThat {
        "The robber that was deactivated is the robber that was moved" using (outputRobber.linearId == inputRobber.linearId)
        "The robber has no changed position" using (outputRobber.hexTileIndex == inputRobber.hexTileIndex)
        "The output Robber has been deactivated" using (!outputRobber.active)
    }

}

@Test
fun aPlayerIsAbleToRemoveAPlayBlockerState() {

    // Get an identity for each of the players of the game.
    val p1 = a.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p2 = b.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p3 = c.info.chooseIdentity()
    val p4 = d.info.chooseIdentity()

    // Issue a game state onto the ledger
    val gameStateIssueFlow = (SetupGameBoardFlow(p1, p2, p3, p4))
    val futureWithGameState = a.startFlow(gameStateIssueFlow)
    network.runNetwork()

    val stxGameState = futureWithGameState.getOrThrow()

    // Get a reference to the issued game state
    val gameState = stxGameState.coreTransaction.outputsOfType<GameBoardState>().single()

    val arrayOfAllTransactions = arrayListOf<SignedTransaction>()
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodes = arrayListOf(a, b, c, d)
    val arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder = gameState.players.map { player -> arrayOfAllPlayerNodes.filter { it.info.chooseIdentity() == player }.first() }

    setupGameBoardForTesting(gameState, network, arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder, arrayOfAllTransactions)

    val gameBoardState = arrayOfAllTransactions.last().coreTransaction.outRefsOfType<GameBoardState>().first().state.data
    val nodeWithMoreThan7 = gatherResourcesUntilAPlayerHasMoreThan7(gameBoardState, arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder, oracle, network)

    val diceRollTriggeringRobber = getDiceRollWithSpecifiedRollValue(3,4, gameBoardState, oracle)
    val futureWithRobberTriggered = arrayOfAllPlayerNodes[0].startFlow(RollDiceFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, diceRollTriggeringRobber))
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithRobberTriggered.getOrThrow()

    val futureWithMovedRobber = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(MoveRobberFlow(gameBoardState.linearId, 5))
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithMovedRobber.getOrThrow()

    val futureWithRobberApplied = arrayOfAllPlayerNodesInOrder[0].startFlow(ApplyRobberFlow(gameBoardState.linearId))
    network.runNetwork()
    val txWithAppliedRobber = futureWithRobberApplied.getOrThrow().coreTransaction

   val playBlockerState = txWithAppliedRobber.outputsOfType<PlayBlockerState>()
            .filter { it.playerBlocked == nodeWithMoreThan7.info.legalIdentities.first() }
            .first()

    var resourceTotal = 0
    val resourcesToSpend = mutableMapOf<TokenType, Long>()
    val playerResources = countAllResourcesForASpecificNode(nodeWithMoreThan7).mutableMap
    playerResources.forEach {
        if (resourceTotal < playBlockerState.price) {
            if (resourceTotal + it.value > playBlockerState.price) {
                val amount = it.value + resourceTotal.toLong() - playBlockerState.price
                resourcesToSpend[it.key] = amount
                resourceTotal += amount.toInt()
            }
            else {
                resourcesToSpend[it.key] = it.value
                resourceTotal += it.value.toInt()
            }
        }
    }

    val futureWithRemovedPlayBlockerState = nodeWithMoreThan7.startFlow(RemovePlayBlockerFlow(playBlockerState.linearId, resourcesToSpend))
    network.runNetwork()
    futureWithRemovedPlayBlockerState.getOrThrow()

    requireThat {
        "All nodes now recognize that the nodeWithMoreThan7 has removed its playBlocker" using (
                arrayOfAllPlayerNodes.all { it.services.vaultService.queryBy<PlayBlockerState>().states.filter { it.state.data.playerBlocked == nodeWithMoreThan7.info.legalIdentities.first() }.isEmpty() })
    }

}

}
```

Comment: " It’s causing a very strange memory leak error. The tests pass when run in isolation but fail when run at once." Please show us the tests you are running.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster - I'll add them as a separate snippet

Answer (score 0):

Move the `generateInGameSpend` function into a Corda service so the code is never checkpointed.

Having large / long running loops can cause issues when checkpointing flows as the stack of the flow keeps growing. I think it can cause issues when persisting the checkpoint / reloading it an a later point.

Code inside of Corda services are not checkpointed and therefore circumvent this issue.

Comment: Just reimplemented as a CordaService. Fingers Crossed!

Comment: Damn, no luck. What's strange is that when I run the tests in isolation they pass. When I run them alongside anything else they fail. `./gradlew clean :allTests:test --tests 'com.robberFlowTests.*'` passes and `./gradlew clean :allTests:test --tests 'com.tradeTests.*' --tests 'com.robberFlowTests.*' fails

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    network.runNetwork()
}
```

To be run before each test case? Because that's what this does. Does running/stopping the network in fast succession work without side-effects?

Side note: If you would want to re-use the network for all the test cases then you could use @BeforeClass (which must be specified on a static method). The method will be run exactly once when the test class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this problem is to tell gradle to throw away the test process every N tests and use a new one. This would tolerate memory leaks.

```
forkEvery(N)
```

The default is 0. i.e. It uses the same test process for infinite number of tests.

> This property specifies the maximum number of test classes that Gradle
>   should run on a test process before its disposed of and a fresh one
>   created. This is mainly used as a way to manage leaky tests or
>   frameworks that have static state that can’t be cleared or reset
>   between tests.
>
> Warning: a low value (other than 0) can severely hurt the performance
>   of the tests

[-Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_execution)